# Sort Dictionary by Key

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Parameter request with Multiple Key Value Dictionary and it's creating perfectly. But every time dictionary is created with random Key - value order. How to Sort or order with respect to Dictionary Keys. 
Example :

```
    [
      "mbappdetails": [
"locationdtls": [
          "ipAdress": "100.105.100.6",
          "locationDtl": "NaviMumbai,Maharashtra",
          "longdtl": "73.0152077",
          "latdtl": "19.1112212"
        ],
        "appdtls": [
          "appregflg": "00",
          "appid": "com.mmcompany.nstapp",
          "applversion": "1.0.70",
          "pushnkey": "cVCzsSyxCLr4l5JPElHWLDiNuoQJcbFmRlN5LFWZM9hN5lYYZnJy_4Kvvu2_fAjBXhGxbKpt"
        ],
        "devicedtls": [
          "deviceserial": "ExtEYNBSO8D85KR7DCEIOSHH",
          "devicemodel": "iPod Touch 6",
          "os": "iOS",
          "simflag": "N",
          "devicesdkversion": "12.10",
          "deviceproduct": "iPod Touch 6",
          "deviceid": "XXXXX-A2F5-XXXX-8EAC-XXXXX",
          "devicemake": "iPod touch",
          "rootflg": "N",
          "devicebrand": "APPLE",
          "osVersion": "12.1.4"
        ],
        "channelid": "XXXXXXRRRRRR"
      ],
      "token": "myToken",
      "signcs": "encrypted_dictionary_key_values_with_signature_key"
    ]
```

Order Should be : channelid,appdtls,devicedtls,locationdtls,token,signcs

**Output must be in Dictionary ONLY.**

Comment: Why do you want to sort it?

Comment: Swift Dictionaries are unsorted.  Why does the order matter?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Hi, I'm trying to sort Dictionary with respect to Key names. Like  ["Name": "Rahul","Age":"26", "Location": "Mumbai","AppName": "nsdApp"]

Comment: The question is **why?** do you want it sorted. Not **how?** :'D.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I need to send Params in particular sorted way only else server will not accept. Its like little complicated encryption with server site.

Comment: Maybe make a simple array of keys ["Name","Age", "Location","AppName"], and access to you dictionary from element from this array

Comment: @Paulw11 Order matters for server site. Server accepting only in some particular orders dictionary only. If is there any other option please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Look up `Codable` protocol.

Comment: First, that's a flaw on the server code. Second, you are misunderstanding the JSON Representation and a Swift Dictionary. It shouldn't matter in your own part, it's just when you transform your Dictionary, or your Struct, back to JSON.

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary. It is an unsorted type. Sorting a dictionary has no meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Dictionary data structure was not designed for any sorted storage. However, you can sort the keys and get it in the form of the array.

```
let dictionary = [
    "A" : [1],
    "Z" : [3],
    "C" : [2]
]

let keysSorted = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<)
```

Then you can iterate over the sorted array and look up dictionary values by keys. Hope it helps!

Comment: As I said before dictionary data structure doesn't preserve the order in which the elements are inserted, nor doesn't support any particular order. However, if you need to send the values to a server in a specified order, I suggest writing your own logic to transfer unordered dictionary values into ordered JSON ones.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add any code so you can try this: (You can change sign according to your requirement. in Which as-sending or descending order you want)

```
let sortedDict = YourDictionary.sorted(by: {$0.0 > $1.0})
```

and if you are trying to call an API then it does not matter in which order params are.

Comment: `let sortedDict = dict.sorted {$0.key > $1.key}`

Comment: What do you mean by output dictionary? Dictionary is an unordered collection

Comment: @LeoDabus One guy Answered my question and Its in Array. Yea I know  and I need helps.

Comment: @user10959828 now your string it is not a valid json

Comment: @LeoDabus Not JSON bro, It's Dictionary :)

Comment: There is not a built in method to do it. I think we have to do it with a model. Model will make dictionary in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You try the below code.

```
    var dict = ["name" : "Test", "user" : "Users" ]
    dict = [String : String](uniqueKeysWithValues: dict.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key 
    })
```

Comment: I want If key = "user" ---- Its order should be 1st, If key = "name" -- 2nd like this order with condition.